# OpenAI not giving response because of invalid request

Tags: java, android, openai-api

What is the error in this code ?? OpenAI not giving response because of invalid request

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d 'What is the Capital of France ?' 'https://api.openai.com/v1/text/generations/'
```

Hard time to get the success in this. Even I tried several solutions found on OpenAI , Google but does not work

```
public class OpenAI {
    private static final String API_URL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/text/generations";
    private static final String API_KEY = "MY_API_KEY";

    public static String generateText(String prompt) throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(API_URL)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + API_KEY)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .post(okhttp3.RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("application/json"), "{\"prompt\":\"" + prompt + "\",\"model\":\"text-davinci-002\",\"max_tokens\":2048}"))
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no endpoint `v1/text/generations`. Did you maybe meant to use [`v1/completions`](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions)?

Comment: @Turing85, even after adding end point , still not working. yeah v1/completions can be used

Comment: ... what? Unless you are a developer of the OpenAI Rest  API, you cannot add an endpoint to it. --- If `v1/completions` can be used, then I recommend rewriting the code to use `v1/completions`.